# How can I get all pixels from canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have the 64x64 canvas field with drawn objects (dots, rectangles and etc.). How can I get the list of colors of all pixels on the canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get information about individual pixels on the canvas.

Comment: Okay. Is there a way to save canvas image as a file?

Comment: @synd: you can save it as a postscript file, or you can query all of the objects and save it in a custom format.